# C++: does caching JSON instead of objects reduce memory consumption?

Tags: c++, json, caching, memory, serialization

I need to cache a large number of `map` in memory. Each `map` will be associated with a `key` for lookup. I'm planning to use `POCO`'s cache framework for this.

If I serialized each `map` into say `JSON`, would that reduce the memory footprint of each cached item? If it does, what kind of saving can I expect - 10%, 50%?

Would you recommend caching plain objects or `JSON`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, yes, caching as JSON would be more efficient, storage-wise, than C++ objects.

The only exception would be if you had an object with a bunch of, eg, int fields and you converted that to a JSON representation (either JSON "object" or JSON "array") as character values.  The JSON character representation could not be nearly as compact as the binary fields, all scrunched together in a single object.

But if you're talking objects that contain lots of pointers to other objects (ie, the typical "object" representation of conceptual JSON) then the actual JSON will be probably between 2x and 8x more compact.

Comment: Thanks. In my case the <map> is a relatively simple <int, string>. Would serialization make sense here?

Comment: If you're converting from a "map" object then the overhead of that is quite high -- likely on the order of 30-100 bytes per entry when everything's accounted for.  Depends to a fair degree on how you define the allocator -- the default allocator will likely be on the high end.